# How to initialize structure in flash at compile time?

Tags: c, eclipse, initialization, embedded, flash-memory

I'm working on an embedded C project and would like to initialize, at compile-time, a structure that is stored in flash (0x1200u), but I keep getting weird compile errors.

```
typedef struct {
    float foo[2];
    ...other stuff...
} MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE

#define MY_FLASH_STRUCT    ((MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE *)(0x1200u)) // <-- error here

MY_FLASH_STRUCT MY_InitdStruct = {
        .foo[0] =  0.12345f;
        .foo[1] =  0.54321f;
        ...other stuff...
};
```

The error I'm getting is "*expected '{' before '(' token*."  Anyone know how to make this work?

### Update

Added to linker file...

```
MEMORY
{
  ... other stuff ...
  m_my_data_section    (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x00001200, LENGTH = 0x00000400
  ... other stuff ...
}

SECTIONS
{
  ... other stuff ..
  .my_data_section :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.my_data_section))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > m_my_data_section
  ... other stuff ...
}
```

C code...

```
static volatile const MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE __attribute__ ((section (".my_data_section"))) MY_InitdStruct = {
        .foo[0] =  0.12345f;
        .foo[1] =  0.54321f;
        ...other stuff...
};
```

I'm not sure the `static` or `const` keywords are necessary, since it's intended only for one-time use to initialize that section of flash memory at compile-time, but it doesn't hurt to restrict the label's usage.

Comment: use the linker script to place the struct, use the language to initialize it

Comment: @Jim Fell what OS are you using?

Comment: @abcOfJavaAndCPP There's no OS. It's a bare metal C project.

Comment: Would it be so bad for the program to assign the wanted starting values to this struct immediately after program entry?

Comment: Why the use of `volatile`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It complicates system initialization because the values are expected to be in flash, programmed at the factory.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 It tells the compiler not to optimize-out the unused label.

Comment: Is the program itself then also pre-programmed into flash (by which I guess you mean PROM-style flash)?  In that case, the fact that it's flash as opposed to some other random-access storage technology seems moot.

Comment: Whomever secretly downvoted with close request due to question being unclear, try reading the post title.  It's pretty clear. *How to initialize structure in flash at compile time?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That makes no sense at all, syntactically that is.

What you need to do is figure out how your compiler supports this, since it's not something you can do with just standard C.

With GCC, you use `__attribute()` to put the symbol in a particular segment, then use the linker script to put that segment in a particular piece of actual memory.

Or, just give your compiler the benefit of the doubt and try a `static const` structure, that *should* end up in flash.

Comment: The catch is that it needs to be at a specific location in memory.  I already have the sections defined in the linker file.  The usage of `__attribute()` may be what I'm missing.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you got me on the right track.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, a ";" is missing after the declaration of MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE

```
typedef struct {
    float foo[2];
    ...other stuff...
} MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE;
```

If it's not a copie/paste mistake, it's the kind of error which could lead to the type of error message you have

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on an embedded C project and would like to initialize, at
>   compile-time, a structure that is stored in flash (0x1200u), but I
>   keep getting weird compile errors.

That's unsurprising, as C does not support what you're trying to do.  You can provide initializers for objects that C allocates, including pointers, but the C language has no concept of objects that exist independently.  Indeed, C makes no guarantees whatever about what happens when you do anything with `(MY_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE *)(0x1200u)` other than convert it back to an integer.

> The error I'm getting is "**expected '{' before '(' token.**"

The compiler is complaining because in

```
MY_FLASH_STRUCT MY_InitdStruct = {
```

, the expansion of `MY_FLASH_STRUCT` is not a type, therefore the construct is not a valid declaration.  Nor is it a valid assignment, but even if it were, assignment statements are executable, and therefore may appear only inside functions.

Assigning an object to a specific address would be a function of the linker.  Whether you can assign an object to the particular address you want is system-dependent, and the mechanism, if any, for doing so depends on your toolchain.